# Expand a TableView inside a TabPane to fill the entire screen

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a TabPane which contains a TextField and a TableView inside. I would the TableView to fill the entire screen in height.

[image: dd]

```
TextField motoristaSB = new TextField();
TableView<Motorista> motoristaTV = new TableView<>(...);
Tab motoristasTab = new Tab("Motoristas", new VBox(motoristaSB, motoristaTV));
tabPane.getTabs().addAll(other, motoristasTab, other, other);
borderpane.setCenter(tabPane);
```

The only way I can get closer of what I want is this:

`motoristaTV.setPrefSize(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() * 0.59, 
Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight() * 0.85);`

but I think is not the best way.

SOLVED: 
Like @Slaw suggested: `VBox.setVgrow(motoristaTV, Priority.ALWAYS);`

Comment: Is the `TableView` not filling up the entire `Tab` or is the `TabPane` not filling up its entire parent? What is the `TabPane`'s parent?

Comment: Parent of `TabPane` is a `BorderPane`. `TabPane` adjust it's size to size of `TableView`

Comment: The center of a `BorderPane` should fill up all available space by default (after the top, right, bottom, and left sides have been sized to their pref sizes). Is the `BorderPane` in another layout? It's possible the `BorderPane` is not filling the vertical space.

Comment: No, `BorderPane` is the root of the scene. The TableView expand with no problem if I use `motoristaTV.setPrefSize(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth() * 0.59, 
Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight() * 0.85);` as I said. But that's not exactly the perfect height and the best way I think

Comment: Sorry, I missed something completely obvious (to me). You're wrapping the `TableView` in a `VBox`. That layout will grow its children horizontally be default, but it will only grow the children vertically to their pref height. Use `VBox.setVgrow(motoristaTV, Priority.ALWAYS)` to override that default behavior.

Comment: Oh god, I would never reach it. Thanks a lot! I have tried a lot things. Just solved!